# Forward keyboard keydown events from html5 textbox to game canvas

Tags: javascript, android

How can I forward all keyboard key hits that mobile browser needs to send to textbox, into my game canvas?

I had to add this kind of inputbox below my game just so that inputbox triggers keyboard on mobile phone screen, and game works ok in iPhone, but not in Android. Game works with physical keyboard of course.

```
<input value="click here" style="font-size: 22px;" autocorrect="off" autofocus type='text' id='foo'><div onclick='$("#foo").focus();'>click here</div>
```

Comment: Just add an `input` event listener to the textbox, and in the handler function, do whatever. Have you tried anything so far? If so, please put it in the question.

Comment: For IOS, it seems my game gets the keyboard events OK; but Android does not deliver the events to game canvas.

Comment: Can you clarify how your game works? What is the textbox doing? Why is it in focus? Did you attach a keydown listener to the canvas element, which works on iOS but not Android? Right now this question will probably be closed soon.

Comment: Thanks Chris, please click here with a mobile phone to see how game and textbox below it works, there is a textbox that you need to click after clicking red button of game, this makes iPhone virtual keyboard to work with game https://rebrand.ly/ut2nh8

Comment: Well, this took some time, but I finally got it (I think). Source: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-margulis-kwvxf Live URL: https://kwvxf.csb.app/ The code creates a new event and I'm setting its `.key` manually, so the question is which property the canvas listener is looking for.

Comment: Awsome, thanks!!  I will test this soonest,  any ideas how to trigger the virtual keyboard to appear without pressing  a link . please submit this as an answer

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only way to get the keyboard to appear in a browser is to get the user to tap on an <input> or <textarea>. The only way to hide that in the context of a canvas featuring a play button is to position the input over the canvas, position some kind of play button on top of the input, then let the click go through to the input. I updated the sandbox accordingly.

Comment: maybe related to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118639

Comment: it seems android has a bug that it cannot generate valid event keycodes :-(

Comment: To be clear, my code is tested and working on Chrome/Android. However, since I'm manually generating the event that is dispatched to the canvas, it's very possible that Construct2's handling is checking a property other than `.key`. I've added the `.keyCode` to the sandbox.

Comment: Thanks for keycode addition,  but now I have added .keycode too to my code, and sending this event to canvas where c2 game is,  there happens still no keyboard input with Android, iPhone is ok, any ideas?  http://rebrand.ly/x31zex

Comment: Chris, also tried to send to window, not working either: window.dispatchEvent(ev2);
Another side note: this game is actually using KeybKeys keyboard handler that is on page, KeybKeys.js,   maybe I should send somehow event to that, but how? This is not working either..    key2 = "A"; keyCode2 = key2.charCodeAt(0); ev2 = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", { key2, keyCode2 }); KeybKeys.keyPress(ev2);

Comment: Chris please send your answer instead of comment to get your points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's apparently not possible to forward the original event, my approach was to create my own and dispatch it to the canvas.
To hide the fact that the user is tapping on an `<input>` I put a button on top and made it ignore pointer events. I also have to keep a character in the text field at all times to prevent the Android keyboard from going back to capital letters.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("#app canvas");
const link = document.querySelector("#app a");
const input = document.querySelector("#app input");
const output = document.querySelector("#app pre");

canvas.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  // console.log("key:", e.key);
  output.textContent += e.key;
});

input.addEventListener("focus", function() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    link.style.display = "none";
    input.value = "a";
  }, 0);
});

input.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  const key = this.value[1];
  const keyCode = key && key.charCodeAt(0);
  const ev = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
    key,
    keyCode
  });
  canvas.dispatchEvent(ev);
  setTimeout(() => {
    input.value = "a";
  }, 0);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 black;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 120px;
}

#app {
  position: relative;
}

#textfield {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  top: 40%;
  text-align: center;
}

#textfield * {
  width: 70px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -35px;
}

#textfield a {
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0.5em;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

#textfield input {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 70px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <canvas></canvas>
  <p id="textfield">
    <a href="">Play</a>
    <input />
  </p>
  Canvas keydown listener output:
  <pre></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: good work,  however I added a few params to input box  to avoid autotype etc.